# What does bitwise_and operator exactly do in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, bit-manipulation

I did not exactly understand what the "bitwise_and" operator does when used in openCV.
I would also like to know about it's parameters.

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and

Comment: Hi OP, since the "checked answer" has 3 downvotes, and is simply a copy and paste from the documentation, you think you could pick my answer as the "correct answer"?  I put a good bit of time into it, and it has 6 upvotes.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**[bitwise_and](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and)**

> Calculates the per-element bit-wise conjunction of two arrays or an
> array and a scalar.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - src1 – first input array or a scalar.
> - src2 – second input array or a scalar.
> - src – single input array.
> - value – scalar value.
> - dst – output array that has the same size and type as the input arrays.
> - mask – optional operation mask, 8-bit single channel array, that specifies elements of the output array to be changed.

Here is an example found on the web:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html

Comment: THis is the documentation of the function.

Answer (score 84):

The general usage is that you want to get a subset of an image defined by another image, typically referred to as a "mask".

So suppose you want to "grab" the top left quadrant of an 8x8 image.  You could form a mask that looks like:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You could produce the above image with Python with:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.zeros(shape=(8,8), dtype=bool)
mask[0:4,0:4] = True
```

Then suppose you had an image like:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For concreteness, imagine that the above image is a simplified representation of the U.S.A. flag: stars in the top left, bars everywhere else.  Suppose you wanted to form the above image.  You could use the mask, and bitwise_and and bitwise_or  to help you.

```
imageStars = np.ones(shape=(8,8), dtype=bool)
for r, row in enumerate(imageStars):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        if r % 2 != c % 2: # even row, odd column, or odd row, even column
            imageStars[r,c] = False

imageBars = np.zeros(shape=(8,8), dtype=bool)
for r, row in enumerate(imageStars):
    if r % 2 == 0:
        imageBars[r,:] = True
```

Now you have an image of stars:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1    
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1    
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1    
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

And an image of bars:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And you want to combine them in a particular way, to form the flag, with the stars in the upper left quadrant and the bars everywhere else.

```
imageStarsCropped = cv2.bitwise_and(imageStars, mask)
```

`imageStarsCropped` will look like:

```
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0    
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Do you see how it was formed?  The `bitwise_and` returns `1` at every pixel where `imageStars` is `1` AND `mask` is `1`; else, it returns `0`.

Now let's get `imageBarsCropped`.  First, let's reverse the mask:

```
maskReversed = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
```

`bitwise_not` turns `1`'s into `0`'s and `0`'s into `1`'s.  It "flips the bits".  `maskReversed` will look like:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now, we will use `maskReversed` to "grab" the portion of `imageBars` that we want.

```
imageBarsCropped = cv2.bitwise_and(imageBars, maskReversed)
```

`imageBarsCropped` will look like:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now, let's combined the two "cropped" images to form the flag!

```
imageFlag = cv2.bitwise_or(imageStarsCropped, imageBarsCropped)
```

`imageFlag` will look like:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Do you see why?  `bitwise_or` returns `1` whenever `imageStarsCropped[r,c]==1` OR `imageBarsCropped[r,c]==1`.

Well, I hope this helps you to understand bitwise operations in OpenCV.  These properties have a one-to-one correspondence with bitwise operations with binary numbers that the computer does to do arithmetic.

Comment: Would be also nice to mention what happens if there are not only 0 and 1, but, for example, 0, 1 and 2 values. Result can be not so obvious :)

Comment: @mins Because of performance considerations. Operations with bool variables are generally platform-dependent and sometimes less efficient than byte operations

Comment: @mins How do you suggest to implement compiler-based optimization for multidimensional array of booleans with heap allocation? For using direct access to bits you need your own bool in that case and support all necessary operations. And even if you're ready to do that, what about masking/unmasking operations? Usually images use at least one byte to represent a pixel. Just think about use-cases, their implementation, and potential profit. If you still find yourself certain about using 'true' booleans in masks, consider creating a pull request :)

Answer (score 9):

**What does the operator do?**

[bitwise_and](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4), [bitwise_or](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4) and [bitwise_xor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga84b2d8188ce506593dcc3f8cd00e8e2c) perform a bitwise operation on elements taken from two arrays, `src1` nd `src2`. [bitwise_not](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0002cf8b418479f4cb49a75442baee2f) is similar. Bitwise means the boolean operation is done between each bit of the values, bit per bit.

**What is the mask parameter?**

It's actually not a Boolean mask (and a Boolean array will be rejected). It's a `uint8` array type where values are checked as being 0 or not. The "mask" has the same x,y shape than the images, but its elements are scalar, that is for an image 100 x 50 x 3 of uint8, the mask must be an array 100 x 50 of uint8.

**How is the mask used?**

This mask determines whether the operation will be performed on the pair of pixels at location x,y. If the element at position x,y in the mask is 0, no operation is performed, and the pixel in the resulting array is 0,0,0 (black). If the mask element at position x,y is not null then the bitwise operation determines the value in the resulting array.

Let's say we want to extract pixels within a circle and make other pixels white. This can be done using to bitwise operation with complementary masks:

[image: openCV bitwise_and and bitwise_or]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = 'images/'

# Read image 330 x 379 x 3 uint8
img = cv2.imread(images + 'sample.jpg')

# Reorder channels as display is done with pyplot
img[:,:,[0,1,2]] = img[:,:,[2,1,0]]

# Create white image, 3 channels 330 x 379 x 3 uint8
w_3c = np.full_like(img, fill_value=(255,255,255))

# Define disk elements
center = (img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2)
radius = int(min(center) * .9)

# Create white disk, 3 channels 330 x 379 x 3 uint8
# and single channel 330 x 379 uint8
d_3c = np.zeros_like (img[:,:], dtype='uint8')
cv2.circle(d_3c, center, radius, [255]*3, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
d_1c = d_3c[:,:,0]

# Extract pixels disk using white disk single channel
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, w_3c, mask=d_1c)

# Add white background
d_3c_i = ~d_3c
final = cv2.bitwise_or(img, d_3c_i)

# Prepare to plot
to_plot = [[(img,'img'),
            (w_3c,'w_3c')],
           [(d_3c,'d_3c'),
            (d_1c,'d_1c'),
            (d_3c_i,'d_3c_i')],
           [(masked,'img & w_3c mask d_1c'),
            (final,'img | d_3c_i)')]]
r = len(to_plot)
c = max([len(l) for l in to_plot])

# Show everthing
fig,ax = plt.subplots(r,c, tight_layout=True)
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        axij = ax[i,j]
        if j < len(to_plot[i]):
            dims = to_plot[i][j][0].ndim
            if dims <= 3:
                axij.imshow(to_plot[i][j][0], cmap='gray')
            else:
                axij.imshow(to_plot[i][j][0])
            axij.set_title(to_plot[i][j][1])
            axij.set_xticks([])
            axij.set_yticks([])
        else:
            axij.set_axis_off()

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

The code can probably be improved.

Answer (score 4):

Just an elaboration to the above answers - not a full answer.  In real life image arrays will have values from 0 to 255, and not just 0s and 1s.  What `bitwise_or` does in this case is to convert each corresponding number in the two images to its binary form, and then do an **or** or **and** or other operation.

Example:

Consider two values 233 and 180.  A `bitwise_or` of these numbers gives us 253 (using `cv2.bitwise_or(np.array([233]), np.array([180]))`.  The binary equivalents of 233 and 180 are 11101001 and 10110100. Doing a `bitwise_or` gives us 11111101 which is the same as 253. This number was obtained by doing an **or** for each digit in the binary equivalents of 233 and 180 (you can verify)

```
bin(233) #0b in the output just means it is a binary number
0b11101001

bin(180)
0b10110100

bin(253)
0b11111101

cv2.bitwise_or(np.array([233]), np.array([180]))
array([[253]], dtype=int32)
```

**and, not and xor** work similarly as **or** by doing the logic operations on the bits of the numbers.

Comment: When would we use a mask that isnt just 1s and 0s?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @mannyglover with the US flag example is a great one! I would also just quickly add that for actual images, any pixel value at 0 (pitch black) would be 'false'. Since false & anything = false, any other pixel with value above 0 would become 0.

This means that after applying bitwise_and, pitch black pixels of the mask would turn respective pixels in the original image pitch black.

Here is an example, done in OpenCV:

Original image: [stack.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsgcU.png)

Mask: [mask.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27sfo.jpg)

After applying `result = cv2.bitwise_and(stack, stack, mask=mask)` : [result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD6xk.jpg)

Comment: This is really misleading, and hindered my understanding by a few hours. Actually, each value will be turned into its binary equivalent, and then a normal bitwise and will be performed. So, a red channel of 57 and another one of 194 will be turned into 111001 and 11000010 respectively.

Comment: My intention on this was not to provide an accurate implementation-focused answer, but rather an intuitive one. Upon rereading this, I do see how it could have mislead you. I'll edit the answer for clarity.

Comment: "*after applying bitwise_and, pitch black pixels of the mask would turn respective pixels in the original image pitch black.*" I take this assumption for valid, but note the operation "src1 and src2" is defined in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) only for mask byte value != 0. The documentation for [bitwise_not](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0002cf8b418479f4cb49a75442baee2f) is even less useful, mask is not mentioned at all.

Answer (score 1):

To someone who is looking for an easy explanation about [bitwise_or](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4)

Lets assume we are going to code cv2.bitwise_or, we have to:

1. Perform bitwise OR of src1 array with src2 array at only those locations where mask is non zero

so assume mask is 100x100 shape with only mak[1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4) = 1 and others all 0. Also src1 is 600x600x3 array all of value 255 and src2 is same as src1.

So after our cv2.bitwise_or operation, we get an output array of shape 600x600x3 with output[1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab85523db362a4e26ff0c703793a719b4) = 255 (as this is the only place we bit wise OR'ed src1 and src2) and the rest of the locations of output array will be 0s.

Answer (score 0):

These operations can be used to selectively modify or extract specific regions of an image. sometimes extract same type region. It is working select, modify, and analyze specific regions of an image.