# OpenCV python bitwise_and() error skin segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, bitwise-operators

Hi everyone I´m working on a Skinsegmentation program on Python with OpenCv, this is the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np



cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Establece los intervalos de el color de piel
    low_skin = np.array([0,5,0])
    up_skin = np.array([65,165,165])

    #Guarda esa matriz en mask
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, low_skin, up_skin)
    #cv.imshow('Segmentacion',mask)

    #Lleva los pixeles de 255 a 1 para multiplicarlo despues
    _,mask = cv.threshold(mask,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    #Erosion del frame
    element_E = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2*5 + 1, 2*5+1), (5, 5))
    Ero = cv.erode(mask, element_E)

    #Dilatacion de los elemntos previa erosion
    element_D = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2*11 + 1, 2*11 + 1), (11, 11))
    dil = cv.dilate(Ero, element_D)

    #Multiplica ambas matrices
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

    cv.imshow('Actual',res)
    cv.imshow('Salida',frame)
    print('Mask')
    print( mask.shape )
    print( mask.dtype )
    print('Dil')
    print( dil.shape )
    print( dil.dtype )


    k = cv.waitKey(30)
    if k == ord('q') or k == 27:
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The problem is that when I try to use the bitwise_and function with mask (which I take from InRange) function it works, but I need to erode and dilatate that mask, so when everything is done I try to apply the bitwise_and function with "dil"
`res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame,dil=dil)`
 and show me the next error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in <module>
TypeError: 'dil' is an invalid keyword argument for bitwise_and()
```

dil and mask arrays show me to be the same size and type.

What could be wrong? Thanks for your Answer

Im working on windows

PD:I have the original Frame and the mask

[image]

When I make the bitwise_and function with these two it gives me the third one:

[image]

But I need to do it with the original and the last one ( "dil")....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=dil)
```

isn't it? Could you explain better what do you want to do with matrices?

[Bitwise_and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333605/what-does-bitwise-and-operator-exactly-do-in-opencv) explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just edited the question so you can see what I am trying to do, I hope I make myself clear.

Comment: But actually both answers were right thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

`bitwise_and` [takes 4 keyword arguments](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) - source1, source2, destination image and a mask. Your TypeError is occuring because you're specifying a keyword argument by name - `dil=dil`. OpenCV doesn't recognise this, therefore you get the TypeError. Maybe you want `res = cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=dil)`?